# How to use Core Audio's Clock API?

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, clock, audiounit

I'm trying to synchronize a visualizer with an audio-track that's being played with the generator audio unit, subtype audioFilePlayer in an AUGraph.

I would like to use Core Audio's Clock API, but I there's not much info out there. I found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatsinCoreAudio/WhatsinCoreAudio.html), and [this](http://objective-audio.jp/cat54/audiounit/).

Does anyone know of a good example in english or any docs on this API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that there is almost no documentation, and the only reference I found was an Apple list serv stating that it's not a fully developed API.

Instead, if you need audio clock data, register a render callback with your generator audio unit like this.

```
AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(m_generatorAudioUnit, auRenderCallback, this);


OSStatus auRenderCallback (
                      void                        *inRefCon,
                      AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
                      const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
                      UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                      UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                      AudioBufferList             *ioData
                      )
{      
    AudioEngineModel* pAudioEngineModel= (AudioEngineModel*)inRefCon;
    pAudioEngineModel->m_f64SampleTime= inTimeStamp->mSampleTime;

    return noErr;
}
```

You can get seconds by dividing the mSampleTime by the sampleRate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this site: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CoreAudioAndAudioUnitsTutorial

Comment: Hey justnS, Thanks for this link. I hadn't seen that source before. I'm not sure if there is anything on the Clock API yet, but there's a lot of material here, so it'll take me some time to get through it.

Comment: Link goes to 404 @justinself

Comment: Sorry @fionbio. That answer is almost 5 years old. I guess it's gone. May have been out of date anyways.